# Можно ли в Django "сквозь" поле ForeignKey записать значение в БД, с которым связано это самое поле?

Tags: python, django

**Имеется модель**

```
class PlaceType(models.Model):
    types = models.CharField(max_length=25, blank=True)

class Place(models.Model):
    place_name = models.CharField(max_length=40, db_index=True)
    place_type = models.ForeignKey(PlaceType)
```

Таблица *PlaceType* на данный момент абсолютно пустая!

Парсю данные и хочу залить их в таблицу.

**Есть код**

```
info_to_db = Place(place_name = cinema, #cinema -> берется из цикла
                   place_type = self.place_type) #self.place_type = 'Кинотеатр'
info_to_db.save()
```

который вызывает ошибку

```
ValueError: Cannot assign "'Кинотеатр'": "Place.place_type" must be a "PlaceType" instance.
```

С ошибкой я вроде разобрался - нужно создать экземпляр этого класса и передать ID, чтото вроде

```
weGotId = PlaceType.objects.get(id=id) #и сделать так
info_to_db = Place(place_name = cinema,
                   place_type = weGotId)
```

но! в данном случае, в базе PlaceType уже должна быть запись "Кинотеатр" с соответствующим id.

- Есть ли возможность как бы "сквозь" ForeignKey добавить в базу *PlaceType* наш "Кинотеатр", и вернуть в базу *Place* соответствующий id?
- Или нужно писать отдельный код\функцию, которая будет проверять наличии в базе *PlaceType* нужной записи, и если записи нету - добавлять ее, а потом уже генерировать *weGotId = PlaceType.objects.get(id=id)* ?

Comment: У Вас странное именование поля в модели `PlaceType` - возможно, вы имели в виду `name` а не `types`. Также, возможно Вам стоит сделать это поле уникальным.

Comment: @soon - поле действительно было названо type и его нужно переименовать в name :) Ступил. Касательно unique - скорее всего вы снова правы. Спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Одно из возможных решений - использовать функцию [`get_or_create`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create):

```
place_type, _ = PlaceType.objects.get_or_create(types=self.place_type)
place = Place.objects.create(place_name=cinema, place_type=place_type)
```

Если объект не существует в базе данных, он будет создан.

Учтите, что если в базе данных находится более одного объекта, удовлетворяющего критериям запроса, то будет брошено исключение [`MultipleObjectsReturned`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/exceptions/#django.core.exceptions.MultipleObjectsReturned)

Comment: спасибо за помощь, а то уже собирался try except писать. Скажите пожалуйста, почему вы в своем решении сделали через .create, а не просто Place(place_name=cinema, place_type=place_type)? Насколько я понимаю, результат один и тот же. Create для визуального восприятия?

Comment: Нет, `create` дополнительно сохранит изменения в БД. В [документаци](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.create) приведен пример.